# How can I break down one node in AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am running AWS Elasticsearch and want to test its node failure scenario. So I was trying to change the cluster setting to remove one node from the cluster but I found I can't do that because AWS ES restriction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_1.

Is there a way for me to bring down one node from AWS Elasticsearch instance to mock a failure scenario?

Comment: Easiest approach would be to start two nodes locally. Elastic installators is pretty easy.

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand. What do you mean by `starting two nodes locally`? I am using AWS Elasticsearch and want to test instances on the cloud. So I don't use local instances in this case.

Comment: I know. But testing cloud vs tesing local is no much difference in your case. You are not testing AWS (this is job for AWS developers), you are testing your alternative scenario in case of errors. Full integration test is not possible because no one will give you AWS insideous infrastructure. What you see as Elasticsearch might be just facade and nothing else, but they are responsible for maintaning API versions.